# Google Calendar :: Update Existing Attendee Status using PHP API

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am using google calendar API V3 . I want to update existing attendee status using `PHP API`. I am using following code. But it seems this code is not updating existing attendee. For example consider (shohag@test.com,enamul@test.com,test@test.com) are attendees of certain event and all of them event status are pending. After executing this code i see only test@test.com in accepted condition. Here is my code.

```
<?php
require_once '../../src/Google_Client.php';
require_once '../../src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';
session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Calendar PHP Starter Application");

$client->setClientId('MYCLIENT ID');
$client->setClientSecret('MY SECRET');
$client->setRedirectUri('MY RETURN URL');
$client->setDeveloperKey('MY DEV KEY');

$cal = new Google_CalendarService($client);
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['token']);
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {

    // First retrieve the event from the API.
    $event = new Google_Event($cal->events->get('primary', 'EVENT ID'));

    $attendee1 = new Google_EventAttendee();
    $attendee1->setEmail('test@test.com');
    $attendee1->setResponseStatus('accepted');
    $attendees = array($attendee1);
    $event->attendees = $attendees;
    $updatedEvent = $cal->events->update('primary', $event->getId(), $event);
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
}
```

How can i change status of existing attendee? Here is update API link `https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update` .Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Just like in the Google Calendar UI, attendee status can only be modified by the attendee their self. If all of these users are in the same Google Apps domain, you can authorize as the attendee via a [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) and change their status as them.

Comment: i need to change status for existing invited attendee. i intended to implement this in iphone app using php API. I need to change RSVP status for certain user by email. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: No, you can't change another attendees status. The user only controls the status for their own invite.